# What will happen to the MS Flow connectors if their usernames password got reset/expired/deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, ms-flow

When we create a new MS Flow which get triggered when items are added/updated inside SharePoint  >> a new connection will be created using the username who created the MS Flow. now my question is what will happen in the following cases:-

1. the password for the creator username got re-set or get expired?
2. the creator username got blocked or deleted inside Office 365?

will any on the above cause the MS flow to stop working? if the answer is yes then how we can overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use **Service Account** with specific account/password rules. Then share the existing flows with the Service Account, and then log in as Service account and update all connectors' accounts to the service account.

Comment: @MatiurRahman thanks for the reply.. but you did not answer my above 2 questions?

Comment: I thought the answer is simple, your Flow will not work

Comment: @MatiurRahman so even if the password is reset the MS flow will stop working? that is weird ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running an experiment with changing passwords for the Flow account. It's been several days and my Flow is still running after the password was changed. Only some actions stopped working. Note that I'm not talking about **disabling** an account. I didn't test this yet.

My conclusion:

- The Flow will actually continue running. Not sure for how long. Chances are it will be working forever. Will update the post if my flow stops working.
- Some actions will stop working within 30-60 minutes after the password change. For example. The Outlook's Send an Email (v2).
- Some actions will continue working for days or maybe weeks. For example the SandGrid's Send Email Notification action.
- Many actions will never stop working. For example, anything to do with variables, date parsing and such.

So it all depends on the connectors your Flow contains. Different connectors last longer after the password change. If you use the Outlook's connectors, then your Flow will break within 30-60 min.

To overcome the issue of the password expiration you have to get a service account and make sure its password never expires. The only disadvantage is that you'll need an extra license applied to this account. In this case choose the cheapest type. For example, E1.

**Update**

I get this popup after a password change, when I open the Power Automate environment:

[image]

And this is how a flow looks like that is still partially running:

[image]

**What to do when you change the password**

- Navigate to the Power Automate environment
- Data > Connections > And for every connecion, click "Fix connection"

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply.. but let say the management refuse to approve creating a service account, then what i need to do if the password expired? do i need to login to MS Flow using the new password and update all the connections? second question, if the management approve creating the service account, then what are the permission required for the service account to be able to connect to SharePoint and update its lists + send emails using outlook connector? can you please advice?

Comment: 1) If the password expires - you need to log in to the Power Automate service and update all connectors. 2) Service accounts needs these licenses: A) SharePoint Online/OneDrive, B) Power Automate, C) Exchange Online, D) Teams (nice to have). Permissions: add this account to the SharePoint sites that you use for data storage.

Comment: So in short i need to create a service account is this correct? instead of using the office 365 admin username? second question, as per our policy the users' password need to be reset every 40 days.. so in this case i need to re-configure the MS Flow connections afterward is this correct?

Comment: 1) for something business critical you want to use a service account with no password expiration. 2) when password expires you need to fix all connections. Correct.

Answer (score 1):

use a "service account with no password expiration" for something that is business critical ????

No wonder people get breached. That is a no-go nowadays.

Microsoft not having a best practice for this ?